# apache shiro 1.5.3 web app tutorial returns 404 error

Tags: web-applications, shiro

I am trying to implement Apache Shiro 1.5.3 in a web app and I am completely new to Shiro. I am using Netbeans 11.3 with Maven as the IDE. I am also using Apache Tomcat 9.0.35 as the container and localhost. I have created a Netbeans project for the published Shiro tutorial from github by itself (no other code or content of my own):

https://shiro.apache.org/webapp-tutorial.html#project-setup
and
https://github.com/lhazlewood/apache-shiro-tutorial-webapp

When executing the web app from the master-level of the tutorial, it works fine (This step does not include initializing or using Shiro itself, but confirms the app project structure is correct so far and that home.jsp and index.jsp are both present and render the expected "Hello World" page to the browser.)

When I add the published web.xml and shiro.ini to WEB-INF per step-1-a and b levels of the tutorial, clean and build the project, compile a new war file with Maven (all of which reports BUILD SUCCESS), restart Tomcat and re-run the web app, I get a 404 error:

HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report
Message JSP file [/shiroproject/home.jsp] not found

However, the home.jsp (and index.jsp) file is clearly as published and in it's proper place; they both work fine without the Step-1a and b changes to web.xml and shiro.ini. Note: I am not familiar with the proposed logger, slf4j, but it is included in the dependencies, logback.xml as published is in the resources folder and I did not change any reference to or content within it. I do not think this is a factor in the current issue (but stay tuned...)

My best guess is that the environment loader listener specified in web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

is not initializing, and is therefore not picking up or filtering the HTTP request as it comes in. Therefore, the requested home.jsp file cannot be found. This listener class is present in the project's declared dependencies. I have no indication besides the 404 error to point to what the problem might be.

If anyone can suggest a cause or path of investigation I would appreciate the help. References to further useful documentation would also be helpful. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The localhost log reported a startup exception:

15-Jul-2020 14:06:10.557 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter [ShiroFilter]
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.shiro.env.RequiredTypeException: Object named 'filterChainResolver' is not of required type [org.apache.shiro.web.filter.mgt.FilterChainResolver].

which led me to this stackoverflow post and a solution that worked:

[SEVERE: Exception starting filter ShiroFilter error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54960713/severe-exception-starting-filter-shirofilter-error)